# Can't delete user folder although I am admin

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday, I created a new account. I made that account admin.
I deleted the old account.

Now I want to delete the `C:/Users/` folder of the old account - since well - the user does not exist anymore.

However even though the new user is administrator, it can't delete that folder.

I receive the following message (roughtly translated):

> You need permissions to execute this process
>
> You need to get the required permissions from "S-1-5-21-1714174702-3467395860-993689402-1001" to make changes to this folder

I googled that ID and it seems to be some kind of security measurement. What do I need to do here?

Comment: Try temporarily to [Disable User Account Control (UAC)](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/112488-enable-disable-user-account-control-uac-windows.html).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was solved by temporarily doing
[Disable User Account Control (UAC)](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/112488-enable-disable-user-account-control-uac-windows.html).